# results page in search center (sharepoint online): is the refiner parameter Site so long that it overlaps?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, refiner

Is there someone here that can tell me if in their non branded (not formatted) Results page in the sharepoint.com/search site collection if you add as a refiner the Site collection url (I think it is called Site) the url is usually too long and it overlaps with the results on the page?

For tenants of O365 the beginning of the URL is always

https://tenant.sharepoint.com...

In my case tenant is already 13 letters.

If it overlaps with the results, what is the best approach to make it better?

Have it wrap with Css? shorten the https://tenant to ...? Use a smaller font?

Comment: Yes, urls are indeed longer to be used as refiner. So, instead of url, we use the title of the site. Is that an option for you ? I can write up an answer related to that.

Comment: by title of the site you mean title of site collection?, I find the refiner by site collection very useful but not by site since all blog subsites are called BLOG and that will create refiners with a lot of duplicates. At times even site titles are long, here is an example 'Portfolio, Projects and Programmes Team'. I bet this will overlap too. I know we should get better at our naming convention

Comment: Yes, I meant title of site collection/site. The one we usually set via site settings > title, desc and logo. But looks like a bummer given that all your blogs have similar title. Yep, longish site titles will overlap as well :(

Comment: You can use the RootWeb Title (site collections do not have a Title property) You can also include a tooltip on hover that displays the URL with the Tenant root and managed path removed.